# Automatic mock of an ES6 class fails (Jest, Vanilla JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mocking

I have the class `FooStorage` that has an Array of `Foo` objects as a member variable. When testing `FooStorage` I want to mock the class `Foo`.
As described at [ES6 Class Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock), an automatic mock is all I need in my case. But when I try to mock the class, it doesn't seem to succeed. Instead when I try to reset the mock with `mockClear()`, I recieve an error message.

Below is the code and the output from jest:

---

`foo.js`

```
class Foo {};

export default Foo;
```

---

`foostorage.js`

```
import Foo from "./foo.js";

class FooStorage {
    constructor() {
        this.storage = []; // Array of Foo objects
    }
}

export default FooStorage;
```

---

`foostorage.test.js`

```
import Foo from "../src/foo.js";
import FooStorage from "../src/foostorage.js";

import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

jest.mock("../src/foo.js");

beforeEach(() => {
    Foo.mockClear();
});

test("if the Foo constructor hasn`t been called", () => {
    const storage = new FooStorage();
    expect(Foo).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

`output`

```
if the Foo constructor hasn`t been called

TypeError: Foo.mockClear is not a function

   7 |
   8 | beforeEach(() => {
>  9 |      Foo.mockClear();
     |          ^
  10 | });
  11 |
  12 | test("if the Foo constructor hasn`t been called", () => {

  at Object.<anonymous> (test/foostorage.test.js:9:6)
```

---

I have already tried to put `jest.mock("../src/foo.js");` before `import Foo from "../src/foo.js";` but the problem wasn't solved.

---

### Edit:

I am using Jest `v. 27.0.6` with [jest-environment-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-node) `v. 27.0.6` and [@types/jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest) `v. 27.0.1`.
I also use the nodejs arguments `--experimental-modules` and `--experimental-vm-modules` so that I can use ES6 imports. I don`t use Babel or anything else. Just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Which jest version are you using? Where you are trying to test is it a plain project in Javascript?

Comment: *I also use the nodejs arguments* - do not. Make sure you *do not* follow any of recommendations from here https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules . This will make Jest run in regular mode, which the answer presumes. . Jest support for native ESM is lacking and will result in problems with mocking. This is what the doc clearly says, *Please note that we currently don't support jest.mock in a clean way in ESM*.

Comment: @EstusFlask I switched to using `Babel` and now the problem is solved. If you want, you can post your comment as an answer or edit your previous one, so that I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic mocking is supposed to work like the documentation explains. If it doesn't and results in said error, this means that the module wasn't mocked, so it would fail with manual mock as well. This can happen because a mock wasn't performed correctly (different case or extension in module path), or `jest.mock` hoisting didn't work (most commonly because of misconfigured Babel transform).

The way this code differs from what's shown in the documentation is that `jest` global is commonly used, while here it is imported value, so it's not the same as using `jest` global. This is obvious and [known reason](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10218) for hoisting to work differently.

It can *possibly* be fixed by ordering dependencies in a way that doesn't interfere with expected execution order:

```
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

jest.mock("../src/foo.js");

import Foo from "../src/foo.js";
...
```

The hoisting of `jest.mock` relies on undocumented, spec-incompliant hack that also depends on Jest version and a specific setup. It's not guaranteed to work because ES imports are expected to hoisted above other statements by specs, and there are no exclusions.

A dated but stable workaround is to switch to `require` that are regular JavaScript function calls and are evaluated as is:

```
let { jest } = require ("@jest/globals");

jest.mock("../src/foo.js");

let { default: Foo } = require("../src/foo.js");
...
```

And an efficient solution is to get rid of `jest` import and set up a generic Jest environment with respective globals, so `jest.mock` could be hoisted as expected regardless of Jest version and other circumstances.

Comment: Changing the order of the import and mock, like you noted in your first Code Block, unfortunately didn't work for me. Also when I remove `import { jest } from "@jest/globals";` I receive the error message `ReferenceError: jest is not defined`. And when I switch to `let { jest } = require ("@jest/globals");` I get `ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

Comment: This is a problem that is specific to your setup. You won't have it in recommended Jest setups. Jest globals (`jest`, `beforeEach`, etc) are exposed by default and not needed to be imported, `require` is naturally available in Node environment where Jest is executed, unless you have unwanted Babel transforms that could affect that.

Comment: I added the information about my setup to my post. Also some jest globals (e.g. `describe`, `test`, `beforeAll`) work without `import { jest } from "@jest/globals";`. Only `jest` seems not to work without it.  Besides I use `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`, so that I can use ES6 imports (This is a front-end project).

Comment: I explained in another comment what's wrong. The problem is that you try to use Jet with native ESM. It's not needed to use `import`. Jest has been supported ESM in recommended config through Babel transforms for years. `"type": "module"` is primarily for Node. It doesn't do any good to frontend project because browsers don't support NPM packages and package.json directly.

Comment: Don't using `"type": "module"` is so old school. I have the same problem, but everybody just give answers to `require` ‍♂️

Comment: @GabrielAnderson That's because JS ecosystem isn't really up to native ESM and falls short on a lot of corner cases, even apart from Jest. As for Jest, it isn't feature complete with native ESM and was originally designed to be used with CJS, with ESM being transpiled via Babel